# how to get data from password protected and closed workbook with in excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I use an ADO on Excel 2007 to get data from closed workbook, the code (regardless of file and sheet names) is:

---

```
Sub TransferData()
Dim sourceFile As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
sourceFile = "C:\Bel.xls"
GetData sourceFile, "Daily Figures", "A13:j102", Sheets("Data -   Daily").Range("N2"), False, False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub GetData(sourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
        SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
' http://www.rondebruin.nl/ado.htm
Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim lCount As Long
' Create the connection string.
If Header = False Then
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
Else
    szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
End If
Else
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    End If
End If
If SourceSheet = "" Then
' workbook level name
szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    ' worksheet level name or range
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
End If
On Error GoTo SomethingWrong
Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1
' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
If Not rsData.EOF Then
    If Header = False Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
    Else
        'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
        If UseHeaderRow Then
             For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
             Next lCount
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End If
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "No records returned from : " & sourceFile, vbCritical
End If
' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub
SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " &   sourceFile, _
           vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

---

the above code does not work with password protected woorkbooks,I also have codes to manage passwords but I really dont know where to put them

```
Sub open_file ()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Bel.xls", password:="123"
End sub
```

---

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Bel.xls", Password:="Password"
```

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285460-how-to-connect-to-password-locked-excel-using-adodb-in-vb6/   2nd from last post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the answer by using this:

```
End Sub
Sub TransferData()
Dim sourceFile As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

sourceFile = "C:\.xls"    Yuor SourceFile Address

Dim xl As Object
Set xl = GetObject(sourceFile)

GetData sourceFile, "YourSourceSheetName", "YourSourceDataRange", Sheets("YourDestinationSheetName").Range("YourDestinationRange"), False,  False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If xl.Application.Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
   xl.Close False  ' close workbook, do not save
   Else
   xl.Application.Quit  ' close excel
End If

End Sub

Public Sub GetData(sourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
' http://www.rondebruin.nl/ado.htm

Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim lCount As Long

' Create the connection string.
If Header = False Then
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
    End If
Else
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    End If
End If

If SourceSheet = "" Then
    ' workbook level name
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    ' worksheet level name or range
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
End If

On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
If Not rsData.EOF Then

    If Header = False Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
    Else
        'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
        If UseHeaderRow Then
            For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
            Next lCount
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End If
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No records returned from : " & sourceFile, vbCritical
End If

' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & sourceFile, _
           vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it this way: https://www.connectionstrings.com/how-to-open-password-protected-excel-workbook/

It prompts for password

Comment: This link says that you must open the protected file first, open it and then use your ADO to get the data.  Is that the order you are doing things? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?644379-Using-RDO-and-ADODB-to-read-from-a-password-protected-excel-file&p=3979133&viewfull=1#post3979133.  And this link looks like it might have a work around.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/how-to-open-password-protected-excel-workbook/

Comment: Yes that's the way to do that. Your link says that you need to use automation. That's what the code does.

Comment: So you have programmatically opened the workbook and unlocked it with the password, but even though it is open and unlocked your routine can not access the data in it?